# Why does GitHub think my code has differences?

Tags: git, github, newline

When I add...

```
# Auto detect text files and perform LF normalization
* text=auto
```

...to my config file then the GitHub app/client says that many (if not all?) of the files in the repository have changed. For many of them it says that the *entire* file has changed even though it obviously hasn't. Obviously this is an issue with line endings but I don't understand why this is happeneing.

It seems that as soon as you tell Git (via the config file) that a file type is text then it throws up differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With text=auto, Git wants to store the files in LF format--it doesn't simply apply a filter to what is there.  As a result, any file that isn't already stored with LF endings will show up as being modified.  You probably want to follow the advice on the [`gitattributes` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) in the [eol conversion](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_end-of-line_conversion) section and do:

```
$ rm .git/index     # Remove the index to force Git to
$ git reset         # re-scan the working directory
$ git status        # Show files that will be normalized
$ git add -u
$ git add .gitattributes
$ git commit -m "Introduce end-of-line normalization"
```

Comment: I thought it was something like that. Thanks.

Comment: Trouble is that every file looks like its been completely changed after that commit. I think the files in the repository might have all been in Windows format.

Comment: Yeah, I really dislike how it works.  I have a template that I use for creating new repositories to make sure line endings are normalized from the start to avoid this kind of problem.  FWIW, Subversion and others have similar issues.

Comment: I got a clean commit after setting 'core.autocrlf = false'. So its now leaving the new-line encoding as is.

Comment: I need to sit down and look at `core.autocrlf` more... I've turned it off on my Windows VM as well.  It's supposed to alleviate problems, but I feel like it introduces more.  Glad you've got things working better for you!

Comment: I found this article helpful... http://timclem.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/mind-the-end-of-your-line/ . I also so wrote a blog post (not sure how accurate it is!)... http://ianwarburton.wordpress.com