# Git format-patch CRLF line ending not being preserved

Tags: git

I'm trying to generate a patch that changes CRLF line endings to Unix line endings. However, it seems like the patch file that is generated has Unix line endings where the CRLF line endings should be in the file. Therefore, when I go to apply the patch it says the patch won't apply. This is due to the CRLF line endings not being preserved in the patch file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems with git format-patch/am (patch does not apply)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140604/problems-with-git-format-patch-am-patch-does-not-apply)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. My repo is mixed line endings and I want to change a file with CRLF line endings to LF while using patches.

Comment: Did you try the `--keep-cr` option?  What did you try?  Show your work, please.